# RecyclerView cells deform when keyboard opened

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a chat inside my app, and the recycler view behave in wired way when the keyboard opened, the cards expands by itself

I tried to disable the recycling ,change the way I build the layout but nothing works,I need to understand why this happened and how to fix it.

The XML layout for the view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="io.thed.cuju.ChatDetailsFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout22"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_image"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Bradley Anderson" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/say_hi"
    layout="@layout/say_hi_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_list_and_input_section"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chat_details_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recived_chat_box_item" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/Gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar12"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/to_be_sent_chat"
            style="@style/cujuEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chat_extra"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/send_chat"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/to_be_sent_chat"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/to_be_sent_chat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat_extra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_media_circle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Adapter

```
    package io.thed.cuju.adapters

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.text.format.DateUtils
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.pddstudio.preferences.encrypted.EncryptedPreferences
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import io.thed.cuju.R
import io.thed.cuju.beans.MessageBean
import io.thed.cuju.beans.UserBean
import io.thed.cuju.constants.*
import io.thed.cuju.customsViews.ZoomImageFragment
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class ChatDetailsAdapter// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
(private val chatList: List<MessageBean>, internal var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    internal var token: String? = null
    internal var user: UserBean? = null

    val SENT_CHAT = 1
    val RECIVED_CHAT = 2

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val current: MessageBean = chatList[position]
        val encryptedPreferences = EncryptedPreferences.Builder(context).withEncryptionPassword(PASSWORD).build()
        var token: String = encryptedPreferences.getString(USER_PREF_TOKEN_KEY, NO_TOKEN)
        tokenForImage = "?x-access-token=" + token
        user = Gson().fromJson(encryptedPreferences!!.getString(USER_PREF_KEY, ""), UserBean::class.java)
        if (user!!._id != current.from) {
            return RECIVED_CHAT
        } else {
            return SENT_CHAT
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChatDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder {

        val v: View?
        if (viewType == SENT_CHAT) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.send_chat_box_item, parent, false)
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recived_chat_box_item, parent, false)
        }

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    lateinit var tokenForImage: String

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = chatList[position]
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        if (current.data.text != null) {
            holder.chat_text.text = current.data.text
        }
        if (current.data.type == "picture") {
            val url = BASE_URL + current.data.media!!.thumbnail + tokenForImage
            Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(url)).fit().placeholder(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder)).into(holder.chat_image)
            holder.chat_image.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.chat_play.visibility = View.GONE

            holder.chat_image.setOnClickListener {
                ZoomImageFragment.newInstance(url).show((context as Activity).fragmentManager, "")
            }
        } else if (current.data.type == "video") {
            val url = BASE_URL + current.data.media!!.thumbnail + tokenForImage
            Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(url)).fit().placeholder(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder)).into(holder.chat_image)
            holder.chat_image.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.chat_play.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            holder.chat_image.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(BASE_URL + current.data.media.link + tokenForImage))
                ContextCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)
            }
        } else {
            holder.chat_image.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.chat_play.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")

        try {
            val dateToBeParsed = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(formatter.parse(current.created_at).time, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
            holder.chat_time.text = dateToBeParsed

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
            holder.chat_time.text = current.created_at
        }

        if (holder.itemViewType == SENT_CHAT) {
            if (current.failed) {
                holder.chat_status!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_seen)
            } else if (current.seen) {
                holder.chat_status!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_seen)
            } else if (current.received) {
                holder.chat_status!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_recived_not_seen)

            } else if (current.sent) {
                holder.chat_status!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.message_sent_to_server)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return chatList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val chat_image: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.chat_image)
        val chat_play: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.chat_play)
        val chat_text: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.chat_text)
        val chat_time: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.chat_time)
        val chat_status: ImageView? = v.findViewById(R.id.chat_status)

    }
}
```

reviced_chat_box_item.xml (sorry for the typo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/recivedChat"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_text"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/content_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Hello buddy, gonna go for a training today?"
                android:textColor="@color/chat_color"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="12 mins ago"
        android:textColor="@color/time_ago"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

send_chat_box_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_text"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/content_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chat_image"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Hello buddy, gonna go for a training today?"
                android:textColor="@color/chat_color"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="12 mins ago"
        android:textColor="@color/time_ago"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chat_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chat_time"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/message_seen" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: This is a screenshot before opening the keyboard]

[image: This is after the keyboard opened]

Comment: Give your recyclerView items layouts

Comment: And quick suggestion - don't use ConstrainLayout. There are still bugs in it.

Comment: how do your item layouts `recived_chat_box_item` and `send_chat_box_item` look like? And is your recyclerview `setHasFixedSize` set to true?

Comment: The height of `recived_chat_box_item` and `send_chat_box_item` is propably set to `match_parent` which it shouldn't.

Comment: @Kuva I didn't understand your first comment but the layout items is already added and question is edited

I used LinearLayout everywhere and the same issue happened

Comment: @donfuxx I set setHasFixedSize to true and the same result.

Comment: @Ch4t4r Despite that will effect the design, I did as you say but it still deform

Comment: do you really need to set `android:layout_height="0dp"` for the recylerview? Have you already tried setting `match_parent` or `wrap_content`?

Comment: on manifests file add windowSoftInputMode as adjustResize

Comment: @PranavAshok Doesn't work

Comment: @donfuxx I tried this also when I convert the whole view to LinearView